# Java popup windows freeze during execute kettle on

Tags: java, swing, popup, jframe, freeze

i have a strange problem, i made a little software on java that execute some jobs i made in kettle. Now, the transformation is going good, everything work, but when i execute transformation i would like to show a message during it

```
public Wait(){
    setTitle("Aggiungi nuovo autore");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension screen = toolkit.getScreenSize();
    setBounds((screen.width/2)-150, (screen.height/2)-90, 300, 180);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(false);
    setContentPane(new Inner());
    setResizable(false);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setVisible(true);
}

public class Inner extends JPanel{
    BufferedImage image;
    public Inner(){
        BoxLayout box = new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
        setLayout(box);
        JTextPane text = new JTextPane();
        text.setText("Attendere il completamento delle operazioni, potrebbe richiedere tempo");
        text.setOpaque(false);
        StyledDocument doc = text.getStyledDocument();
        SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("extra/loading.gif");
        JLabel label = new JLabel (icon);
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,20)));
        add(label);
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,20)));
        add(text);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(java.awt.Color.DARK_GRAY, 3);
        setBorder(border);
    }
}
}
```

and i run it in this part of controller

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            aggiungi.setEnabled(false);
            Wait wait = new Wait();
            wait.toFront();
            for (int i=0; i<model.effectivilyCount();i++){
                int removed = 0;
                int c = executeCommand(model.getValueAt(i, 0),model.getValueAt(i,1));
                if (c==0) {
                    model.removeRow(removed);
                    model.fireTableDataChanged();
                }
                else if (c==1) ;//errore fatale da implementare
                else if (c==2) ; //segna di rosso e lascia stare nella tabella
            }
            wait.dispose();
            aggiungi.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

Now, java open the new window (wait) and disable the main window  (aggiungi), but it doesn't show what wait contain :(. What i can do about?

PS executeCommand(String,String) run the kettle transformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a threading issue, likely caused by the executeCommand method. You're calling this on the Swing event thread and it's tying up the thread, making your GUI unresponsive. Better to put it in a background thread such as that supplied by a SwingWorker.

In addition, it looks like you're showing a 2nd window that's possibly a JFrame. If so, you're probably better off showing a modal dialog, as the modal part will make your main window inactivated until the dialog is no longer visible.

Comment: I'm running excecuteCommand from controller (aggiungi and Wait are two differents classes). I'm going to try Kettle with a different thread :)

Comment: @Neo87: it matters little what class is involved since what really matters for your misbehavior is what thread it's called on. If you use a background thread, do take care to make sure that Swing calls are made on the Swing event thread.

Comment: i think i understand what you would like to say. My misbehavior is that if i calls the like this, i'm locking event thread with my calls. So, probabily, a good solution could be to create a little thread who will calls the massive kettle transforms

Comment: @Neo87: yes something like that. A SwingWorker will help you create this background thread while also making it easier to transmit data back to the Swing GUI in a safe manner.

Comment: you are a genius, i made a little thread who runs kettle transformation and stop the Wait window throught the same instance of MiniController, it is working fine :D

Comment: @Neo87: I'm glad you've got it working, but again, I can't stress enough the importance making sure that your Swing calls, such as both calls to the (JTable?) model, are done on the Swing event thread. For more on the Swing event thread, please read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).